# Proof that 1D bound states are non-degenerate without Wave Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Most proofs I see that all bound states of a quantum system are non-degenerate use the wave-function representation. How can we prove it using only Dirac notation, without resorting to the wave picture?

Comment: Do you mean non-degenerate in your question body? Also, $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$, so couldn't you say the arguments are the same, or maybe I am missing something. Perhaps you could expand on both what you have seen and what you want to be shown.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I've already fixed it.

Comment: Perhaps you might translate as much of [this related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136646/degeneracy-in-one-dimension) to observe that your are very much considering the space dependence of the potential and the wave function involved and wf normalizability. The question is *why on earth* would you like to abstract away from space features?

Comment: I believe the question would be why not?

Comment: Why not hike the Alps in flipflops?

Comment: I mean I want to learn how to.

Comment: Seriously, my point is that for TISE *x* and *p* are very asymetric, and it is all about *x* properties of the potentials and their functional analysis. Abstracting further to include possible velocity-dependent potentials, which would be the only excuse for the bra-ket generalization would muddy the waters instead of illuminating it. The Messiah QM text overcomplete treatment reminds you why.

Comment: I don't want to include velocity-dependent potentials, I just want to know how to prove it in bra-ket notation.