# Degeneracy in one dimension of wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

In 1D there are no degenerate bound states. What is the physical intuition behind the previous statement?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136646/2451